# Migrate database generated by entity framework to sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-migration

I made a application with database generated by entity framework(code first) and now I want to make my application working on other computer. I instaled sqlserver there and made all the tables in the database (I am working just with localhost database). Now I wanted to connect my database with application, I thought that all what I need to do is just change connection string. But I am not able to connect to my database.

Here is how looks my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="InzerceConnection" connectionString="Data source=VRBASPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdvertisingSystemDB;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />
  <!--This is how my connection string works by default <add name="InzerceConnection" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=Inzerce_Dev;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />-->
<!--<add name="InzerceConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AdvertisingSystemDB;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I tried a lot of combination of connection string, but none worked.
I am not sure how to setup my config file to connect to database.

Thank you for any advice.
Sory for my english its not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your database context.
Database context and name attributes should be the same.

For Example

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
    }
}
```

ConnectionStrings in your app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DatabaseContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data source=VRBASPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdvertisingSystemDB;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am sure that database in my sql server is same as the one was generated by entity framework (just name of database is diferent). And I also tried change the name of the connection in config file to be same as name of my DbContext class but still it doesnt work.

Comment: providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" add this attribute in connectionStrings

Answer (score 0):

In your context override the OnConfiguring method.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InzerceConnection"].ToString();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connstr);
    }
```

Comment: And to find your correct ConnectionString try to connect to the database with visual studio's database connection wizard

Comment: No suitable method found to overide. My database context is located in library project if it helps.

Comment: Add this method to your DbContext and it should point to your ConnectionString in app.config